# how to use filter and orderby with isolated directive?

Tags: angularjs, filter, directive

I make a custom directive with isolated scope and is get data also in that directive but now my filter and orderby not working here is my directive:

```
    <div my-data remoteurl='url' filter='test'>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
 (function() {

 'use strict';

   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myAppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/new.json';
  $scope.filter= 'test';
  $scope.orderBy= 'sortExpression';
}])
.directive('myData', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      remoteurl: '=',
      filter: '=',
      orderBy: '='
     // orderBy:'sortExpression':'order' ;
    },
    templateUrl: 'DataTable.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      $http.get(scope.remoteurl)
        .success(function(response) {
          scope.names = response.data.children;
        });
    }
  };
}]);
```

})();

DataTable.html

```
<ul>
     <li >
     <table  width="80%" id="dataTable" align="center" name="table1">
         <tr>
             <td><strong>Title</strong></td>
             <td><strong>Link</strong></td>
             <td><strong>Score</strong></td>
         </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="x in names |filter:test|orderBy:sortExpression:order ">

             <td id="title"><a  ng-href="{{ x.data.url}}">{{x.data.title}}</a></td>
             <td ><a ng-href="{{ x.data.url}}">Link</a></td>
             <td>{{x.data.score}}</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</li>
```

i am passing all parameters but only url is working filter and orderby is not working can anyone correct me?

Comment: I guess your tr should look like this:
`<tr ng-repeat="x in names |filter:filter|orderBy:orderBy">`. Give it a try. Next time would be nicer if you could prepare a Plnkr, so others can investigate directly in the code. See [http://plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co) -> New -> Angular 1.x

Comment: @ilmgb its working but how can do asc and desc?

Comment: See the angular docs at [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy). It states "An expression can be optionally prefixed with + or - to control ascending or descending sort order (for example, +name or -name). If no property is provided, (e.g. '+') then the array element itself is used to compare where sorting."

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as correct. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the isolated scope. In general you are passing the variables in a correct way - from the controller into the directive via the `=`-notation.

You forgot to pass the orderBy to the directive, as well as understanding how filters and orderBy generally work. Please take a look into the documentation for [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) and [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) and look at the examples as well.

Corrected directive code, now with the controller's orderBy scope variable passed into the directive.

```
<div my-data remoteurl='url' filter='test' order-by="orderBy">
</div>
```

As I have already commented, your table rows code should look like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:filter | orderBy:orderBy">
```

In the controller I have set up the following filter and orderBy strings.

```
$scope.filter= 'obama';
$scope.orderBy= '-data.score'; //the "-" stands for reverse ordering
```

When you define a filter like this `filter:test` the filter is based on a scope variable called test, e.g. `$scope.test`. In your scope, the filter is inside the scope variable `$scope.filter`, so correct call of your filter is `filter:filter`.

I have set up a working plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/FGZVaPrvbUcdvNRnKMk4?p=preview